# PHP - preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, date, preg-match

I'm not very good with expressions...  I've looked at some online tutorials, but I'm still not getting it.  Basically, I'm trying to return `TRUE` if a string is formatted like this:

4 digits + space + 2 digits and convert it to a date.

So, the string will look like: `2010 02`, and I'm trying to output `February, 2010`.

I'm trying to use `preg_match`, but I keep getting

> { is not a modifier...

*EDIT*

Per the first 2 responses, I changed it, but am getting a fatal error on the first and the same unknown modifier error on the second:

```
if (preg_match('/([0-9{4}]) ([0-9]{2})/iU', $path_part)) {
    $path_title = date("F, Y",strtotime(str_replace(" ", "-", $path_title)));
}
```

Also, just tried the more in-depth version in the first response, and while the error goes away, it doesn't change the output:

```
$path_part = '2010 02';
if (preg_match('/^(\d{4}) (\d{2})$/', $path_part, $matches)) {
    $path_title = $mon[(int)$matches[2]] . " " . $matches[1]; // prints Feb 2010
}
```

Comment: /([0-9{4}]) ([0-9]{2})/ is incorrect. Use /([0-9]{4}) ([0-9]{2})/ or 
/(\d{4}) (\d{2})/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm trying to return TRUE if a string is formatted like this: 4 digits + space + 2 digits

```
return preg_match(/^\d{4} \d{2}$/,$input);
```

To convert to date you can try something like:

```
$mon = array('','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec');
$date_str = "2010 02";

if(preg_match('/^(\d{4}) (\d{2})$/',$date_str,$matches))
{
        print $mon[(int)$matches[2]] . " " . $matches[1]; // prints Feb 2010
}
```

Comment: Ok, I just did.  I tried the longer explanation and the errors go away, but it doesn't output anything different.  Still prints out 2010 02

Comment: You need to ensure that the number of the month is only in the valid range of 1..12.

Answer (score 1):

```
$in = "2010 02";
if(preg_match('/([0-9]{4}) ([0-9]{2})/i', $in, $matches)) {
        echo date("F Y", strtotime($matches[2] . "/1/" . $matches[1]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
preg_match('/([0-9{4}]) ([0-9]{2})/iU', $input);
```

Comment: This one's wrong. The first character group is mixed up with the mutliplier. It should be `[0-9]{4}` instead

Comment: I tried this, and I get the same error:

warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '{'

Answer (score 0):

Without having any detail as to your actual code, the following should work:

```
<?php

$str = '2010 02';

$months = array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');

if(preg_match('/([0-9]{4}) ([0-9]{2})/', $str, $match) == 1){
    $year = $match[1];
    $month = (int) $match[2];
    echo $months[$month - 1] . ', ' . $year;
}else{
    //Error...
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [T-Regx](https://t-regx.com) library

```
$string = '2010 02';

pattern('\d{4} \d{2}')->match($string)->first(function (Match $match) 
{
    $year = $match->group(1);
    $month = $match->group(2);
});
```